# Sequelize: Why am i getting Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column Receiver.receiver does not exist

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize seems to be looking for Receiver.receiver  which should be Receiver.id. i have a Message entity which is made up of two fields of type User titled, receiver and sender.

I tried retrieving it like this using Sequelize

```
   Message.hasOne(User,{foreignKey: 'receiver', as: 'Receiver'});

Message.hasOne(User,{foreignKey: 'sender',as: 'Sender'});

User.belongsTo(Message);

Message.findOne({ where : {id:1},

    include: [{

        model: User,

        as: 'Receiver'

    },

        {

            model: User,

            as: 'Sender'

        }

    ]

}).then(function (message) {



});
```

what could be the issue?

I added the code snippet of the use where i used the findOne method and Changed the hasOne to BelongstoOne. In my code, I get a socket call with a messages data which is then stored in the database, then in the promise the Message is retrieved and sent to the socket who is the receiver. (Note: each message consists of two Users, who are either sender or receiver and there are alot of messages which can be between the same sender and receiver ).

```
socket.on('send message', (data) => {

        //todo connect to the gambeat db and update the users info to online

        Message.create({

            time: moment.utc().format(),

            isread: false,

            message: data.message,

            messagestatus: 'DELIVERED',

            receiver: data.receiver.id,

            sender: data.sender.id,

        }).then(function(message) {

            Message.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'receiver', as: 'Receiver'});

            Message.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'sender',as: 'Sender'});

            Message.findOne({ where :

                {id: message.id},

                include: [{
                    model :User,
                    as: 'Receiver'},

                    {
                        model :User,
                        as: 'Sender'
                    }
                ]



            }).then(function (message) {


                var soc = users_socket.find(soc => Number(soc.uniqueId) === Number(data.receiver.id));

                soc.emit('disperse message', message);


            });




        }).catch(function(err) {

                console.log(err, err);

        });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
Message.hasOne(User,{foreignKey: 'receiver', as: 'Receiver'});
Message.hasOne(User,{foreignKey: 'sender',as: 'Sender'});
```

**To :**

```
Message.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'receiver', as: 'Receiver'});
Message.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'sender',as: 'Sender'});
```

> **Reason :**
>
> `HasOne` and `BelongsTo` insert the association key in different
>   models from each other. HasOne inserts the association key in target
>   model whereas BelongsTo inserts the association key in the source
>   model.

Comment: isnt belongsTo for a one to one rleationship, because it is returning an error when i try to use the same user and save it to another message entity

Comment: Hasone and belongsto work in same way only difference is inserting foreign key

Comment: okay okay, i will try it later in the day and let you know what i got

Comment: so i tried it, the first insert worked, but after trying another save i got " SequelizeAssociationError: You have used the alias Receiver in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases."

Comment: Please post your insert query also then

Comment: I have added the insert query, and additional information that might assist you.